# list a loop in ascending order with foreach (1 , 2 , 3 ...)

Tags: php, arrays

some way to enumerate a loop in ascending order with foreach

```
<?php  
$semana=array("lunes","papa","miércoles","peras","viernes","sábado","domingo");
foreach ($semana as $dia) {
        echo $numero.','.$dia;
        }
?>
```

The result would be something like this:

```
1 , lunes
2 , papa
3 , miércoles
4 , peras
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: you can manage an counter or just use the key of your array `foreach ($semana as $numero => $dia) { `

Comment: `foreach ($semena as $numero => $dia)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php 
$semana = array("lunes","papa","miércoles","peras","viernes","sábado","domingo.");
foreach ($semana as $numero => $dia) {
    echo ($numero + 1) . ',' . $dia;
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that `echo` accepts several arguments separated by comma. This way you can avoid a useless string concatenation and simply display all what you want: `echo $numero + 1, ' , ', $dia;`